# Duvida sobre o ReportViewer C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, reportviewer

Boa Noite, gostaria de saber se tem como colocar um texto no relatório por exemplo estou fazendo um recibo e coloquei um textbox e gostaria de colocar tudo na mesma linha por exemplo Recebi da(o), nomeRazao_cli, portador do CPF, cpf_cli, a importância de(valor por extenso).

nomeRazao_cli e cpf_cli estão vindo do banco de dados.

Ficaria assim no relatorio: Recebi da(o), Maria Aparecida, portador do CPF, 111.111.111-11, a importância de(vinte reais).

Agradeço

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você precisa adicionar uma expressão/fórmula. Para concatenar os campos é simples. Seria algo assim:

```
= "Recebi da(o), " & Fields!nomeRazao_cli.Value & ", portador do CPF," & Fields!cpf_cli.Value & ", a importância de " & Fields!vlExtenso.Value
```

Agora o valor por extenso é algo mais complicado, eu te indico pegar uma função, e rodar essa função no banco dados:

```
select nomeRazao_cli, cpf_cli, fn_numeroExtenso(valor_recebido) as vlExtenso ...
```

O código da função do número por extenso costuma ser muito grande e não tenho nada aqui no momento, mas vou deixar links para você se basear.

Também daria para fazer essa função no C#, no caso não sei como você está pegando os dados, se está jogando um `DataTable` ou `IEnumerable<T>` como fonte de dados do relatório, mas independente disso você poderia usar essa função, seria algo assim:

```
List<Recibo> recibos = repositorio.GetRecibos();
foreach(var recibo in recibos)
   recibo.vlExtenso = Funcoes.ValorPorExtenso(recibo.valor);
reportViewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource("dados", recibos));
```

**Links da função por extenso no SQL ou C#**

https://gist.github.com/ycaroafonso/7995399

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/pt-BR/3ca5b29e-af07-4b04-a4a0-60c6a6afcec3/transformar-valor-r-575-em-por-extenso-cinco-reias-e-setenta-e-cinco-centavos?forum=transactsqlpt

https://gabrielrb.net/2013/12/23/conversao-de-numero-e-porcentagem-para-extenso-em-c/

**Referência para fórmulas do Report Viewer:**

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms252095(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: Amigo Murilo muito obrigado me ajudou bastante em questão dos números por extenso tenho um classe que faz isso,Valeu pela força